# TestLink 1.9.5 and QueryMetrics

Tags: metrics, testlink

i have another problem in TestLink. I'm using 1.9.5 version of this app, and my problem is following: in this version I don't have a feature which was available earlier in TestReports section - QueryMetrics. that was really nice feature, but now it disappeared and I don't know why. Somebody getting familiar with testlink can get me answer? And finally, is it possible to add this feature in 1.9.5 TestLink (simple modification in code) for example from older testlink versions? Many thanks for help, cause I don't have an access to TestLink forum:
http://www.teamst.org/forum/
I wrote to them and I sent request to get an account but I didn't get answer.

Comment: No one doesn't know TestLink here? Please, this is really imoprtant for me. If I won't get an answer I try to download older version of TestLink and I cut some code responsible for query metrics and try to put it into 1.9.5 version, but it can be really hard to do it.

Comment: OMG, I'm trying to put code responsible for query metrics from 1.9.3 version into test link 1.9.5. This is horrible, cause many, many classes and files changed and I'm trying to digging in all this things and it's really hard task (harder, cause my knowledge about php is close to zero ;)). I'm wondering, is there a chance that query metrics returned in testlink 1.9.6? Cause this version will be relased 10.03.2013. This will be solution for my problem.     EDIT: Ok, I got test link account, so I'll ask on testlink forum

Comment: You can only got from 1.9.3 the idea and the output generated, but you need to rewrite the whole logic.
That is the work we have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the TestLink and was suprised with this and with their reply how difficult is to provide this metric.
Actually it's simple enough, fortunately the TestLink is using OOP. It means it does not metter how many changes you have - you need just a few simple steps:

1. copy related php files from 1.9.3: 
   like resultsMoreBuilds.php and resultsMoreBuildsGUI.php to lib/results
2. copy all classes it depends on:
   like lib/functions/results.class.php - it's absent at 1.9.4-1.9.6 - and may be copied as is and testproject.class.php - in this case you need to copy it as additional class i.e. rename to testproject3.class.php for example.
3. edit the additional class itself :
   to realy have an additional class i.e. 
   change "class testproject extends tlObjectWithAttachments" to "class testproject3 extends tlObjectWithAttachments"
4. use this additional class:
   at lib/functions/results.class.php update 
   "include('testproject.class.php');" with "include('testproject3.class.php');"
   and "$tproject_mgr = new testproject($this->db);" with "$tproject_mgr = new testproject3($this->db);"

I beleive that's it at least to describe an idea , hope in this case the metric becomes working, but without related defects strings - this is because issue tracking interface was changed. But if you get an idea you may use it here as well. Unfortunately a description may be longer than desired :)